# PureScript - How to Add or Subtract NewTypes

Tags: purescript

Consider this intuitive example, where one attempts to use the (+) operator on two NewTypes derived from Number:

```
module Main where

import Prelude (Unit, (+))
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console (logShow)

newtype Balance = Balance Number

a :: Balance
a = Balance 7.18

b :: Balance
b = Balance 16.50

c :: Balance
c = a + b

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  logShow c
```

However, attempting this operation produces the following error:

```
No type class instance was found for
  
    Data.Semiring.Semiring Balance
  

while applying a function add
  of type Semiring t0 => t0 -> t0 -> t0
  to argument a
while inferring the type of add a
in value declaration c

where t0 is an unknown type
```

So, in essense, the question is

#### How do you operate on newtypes as though they were the type they were derived from?

So ideally this solution would also work when concatenating two values of a new type based on string, or comparing two values of a new type based on boolean, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newtype`s do not inherit the typeclass implementations of the underlying type. You either have to implement it manually, or if it's supported, [derive the instance](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/guides/Type-Class-Deriving.md). In this case, PureScript supports deriving addition (Data.Semiring):

```
newtype Balance = Balance Number

derive newtype instance Semiring Balance
```

Full code (you can copy paste it into https://try.purescript.org/ to try):

```
module Main where

import Prelude (Unit, (+))
import Data.Semiring (class Semiring)
import Data.Show (class Show)
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console (logShow)

newtype Balance = Balance Number

derive newtype instance Semiring Balance
derive newtype instance Show Balance

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  logShow ((Balance 7.18) + (Balance 16.50))
```

Output:

```
23.68
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is very much a feature, rather than a flaw, in the language. One of the main reasons for wrapping an existing type in a newtype is to give it its own typeclass instances - this would not be possible if all instances were automatically taken from the underlying type.

Comment: What a great answer - learning as much as from a book just by reading and implementing it good stuff